# Applying linseed oil on old weathered plywood

Tags: painting

Can I put linseed oil on a older weathered plywood shop door and then paint it with outside fence and deck paint?

Comment: Should be able to put the linseed or paint.  Not sure if you can paint over linseed.  Good cleaning and prep before doing either will make them last longer.